# Time index in TD(0) return

Tags: reinforcement-learning, temporal-difference-methods

in TD(0). for the return we have:

$G_{t:t+1}=r_{t+1}+\gamma v_t(s_{t+1})$.

Why is the time index on right hand side in $v$ is $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TD(0) is essentially an *iterative* online algo and your above one-step return TD target is used for TD error to further update value estimation of state $s_t$ at time step $t$, thus the one-step return can only be expressed in terms of value estimation of state $s_{t+1}$ at the same time step $t$.